# ReactJS: REST post request works on Postman but get an error: 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0' on browser?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, reactjs, postman

I have a REST API server up and when I make a post request on Postman it correctly returns a JSON in the form of e.g. `{user:testing123}` but if I make the post request on the web browser with the following:

```
return function(dispatch) {
  fetch('http://apiservertest:3000/username', config)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(user => {
    console.log(user)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error: ", error)
  })
}
```

But then `console.log(user)` logs: `Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

So I switched from `response.json()` to `response.text()`, it simply logs the web's HTML files in text.

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: The issue is that `response.json()` only works if you have a JSON response body, but you're dealing with an HTML body, so some reason, which obviously can't be parsed as JSON. You seem to understand already (maybe?) that you're dealing with HTML, based on your statement that "it simply logs the web's HTML files". Do you know why you're getting HTML body in the browser but a JSON body in Postman, or is that the heart of your question? In any case, we'll probably need to see request and response HTTP headers to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Also, the `{user:testing123}` string you posted is not JSON; it would need to be `{"user":"testing123"}`. That's definitely not causing the issue you're describing here, but may cause an issue later, if that's not just a typo in your question.

Comment: What kind of server is this? It seems like you are possibly running into an error page when requesting from your webapp, but Postman doesn't get this error.